# Can I use other brands of window cling in a cricut?

Tags: material-selection, cutting

Say I have [some non-Cricut window cling](http://www.joann.com/cling-vinyl-9inx12in-sheets/8258790.html) and a [Cricut Explore](http://us.cricut.com/home/learn/machines/explore-family).  Cricut also sells [their own window cling](https://shop.cricut.com/en_us/supplies/cutting-materials/window-cling/window-cling.html), but I have none.

Is there any harm in using non-Cricut brand materials for a project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly you can.

Cling material is vinyl and there is nothing special about the product on which Cricut puts its name.

If you go too far afield in acquiring non-brand name supplies you might want to pay attention to the thickness and adjust the material setting for your machine accordingly.

Comment: I suspected this was the answer. The only thing that might be worth adding to this logic is I would not be surprised if there was a warranty clause that is voided by the use of 3rd party materials....

Comment: @Matt Good point.  There is such a clause in the warranty, but it does not necessarily mean that using third party materials will cause any harm.

Comment: I believe that in the US, it's illegal for a company to void a warranty because someone used a non OEM supply.